# Can you create a xml request and parse response using the code generated by wsdl.exe using wsdl?

Tags: c#, web-services, wsdl

The customer has a REST middleware client that bridges the internet and their intranet Web service.

So, I have to wrap a web service request in a REST invoke and take the web service response from the REST result.

I have the wsdl of their web service. So, I generated the reference.cs from it using wsdl.exe

Can I call the generated code in a way to create a request message? I would then stuff the request in the REST call and then can I stuff the response I get back from the REST service and access the response using the generated code?

Perhaps I am going about this wrong? Is there a better/easier way?

Comment: Can you post some of the code you have? You should be able to call their service and process a response. In Visual Studio, you should be able to add a "Web Reference" to your project, which will generate the necessary classes for you and make them available to your C# project.

Comment: No, the web service is behind a firewall. The only way to access it is through a REST service wrapper, so no direct access to the web service at all

Comment: Is there middleware client a glorified proxy server then? If so, you should be able to point your SOAP service object to use their middleware URL. If not, then you might need to hit a specific URL with certain parameters, which would then make the SOAP request on your behalf. You might want to talk with your customer about how to consume this API.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's a bit more glorified than that, there is a wrapper text that needs to be placed around the SOAP request. So, cannot use it as a connection URL